# Text field is null while running but not in inspector

Tags: unity, gui

I've encountered a strange problem. In my game I have a prefab called UiManager. It has two public Text-fields, one for score, and one for lives. I only have one instance of this prefab and I've assigned the two Text-fields with two text-objects. Yesterday it worked well.

[image]

Today I reopened my project and started the game and when I collected a life I got a null reference on the text field Lives. Now clearly it is not null, I tried to delete my instance and recreate it and then assigning the Text-fields again, and it worked.

I then saved my project and exited Unity and reopened my project and now the issue was back again, a null reference on Lives. Also I noticed that it is not possible to apply ui-objects to a prefab (?).

Anyway, does anyone have any idea why this occurs?

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

There must be only one reason in my view.

If you are trying to attach any object to *prefab* from *hierarchy* then your information will be last till exactly that very prefab exists.

Means if you create a new instance of that prefab then your fields will be empty.

But **YES** your prefab will save the reference if you drop elements from Unity Project Explorer, not from Hierarchy.